# How to show multiple pages of a Power BI embed report when viewed in Mobile layout within the host application

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an Power BI embed application coded in Angular and C# backend. The Power BI reports are working fine when viewed in the normal web layout, but when in Mobile layout, the reports that have multiple pages are showing only one page by default, the other pages are not showing. I would like to show the other pages also when in mobile layout together with their tabs. Not sure if this has to be configured in PowerBI(which I could not find) or should I code a customized navigation in the Angular app for these pages to show.

[Report in web layout- pages are showing as tabs below the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUEKb.png)

[Same report in mobile layout- only default page is showing, other pages cannot be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b2Da.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this link. You could find the next method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/report.report#setPage_string_

**report.setPage(string)**
Sets the active page of the report.

Typescript

```
function setPage(pageName: string)
```

Javascript

```
report.setPage("page2")
 .catch(error => { ... });
```

Also you can get all the pages and check if theres a mobilew view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/mobile

TypeScript

```
hasLayout(layoutType: any): Promise<boolean>
The hasLayout method will return a boolean if the page has the specified layout type.
```

Javascript

```
let pages = await report.getPages();
let mobileLayout = pages[0].hasLayout(models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait);
```

Another useful Link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/mobile-layout-support/